# Add one value of 0.1 to an objects position to reflect in all three transforms in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to add 0.1f to an object's position so that all 3 transforms (x,y,z) are effected?

I know the possible way is

```
object.transform.position += new Vector3(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f);
```

but I was looking for:

```
object.transform.position += 0.1f; //something like this
```

EDIT: I do not understand why I have down votes for this. All I was looking for a different approach. I know the Unity basics very well.

Comment: You need to set the position to a Vector3 not a scalar value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having to type it multiple times you can also simply use

```
transform.position += Vector3.one * 0.1f;
```

the [`*` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_multiply.html) multiplies each component of the `Vector3` by the given `float` where [`Vector3.one`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-one.html) is a shorthand for writing `new Vector3(1, 1, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You add a new vector with whatever value you want as follow:

```
gameObject.transform.position += new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read [the Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) `transform.translate(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f);` will move +0.1 in all directions.